# Loading indicator on file download with page redirect

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to have a loading indicator while a pdf is being generated. I redirect to a php page page for the generation of the pdf and then the pdf is downloaded. The thing is, you never actually leave the original page. It simply downloads the file. Is there a way of telling when the page is done processing so I can have a loading indicator appear when it starts and disappear when it's done?

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery FileUpload plugin: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

you'll get the equivalent of a promise.done() where you can hide the loading inidicator.